# In the extract below, is there a rule as to why there shouldn't be a comma before "but"?

Tags: grammaticality

In my native language, in this case, a comma before "but" would be necessary. So I would naturally feel the need to put it there. But what about the English language? Why shouldn't be there a comma? Is there any specific rule to that?

Example: ...it’s often followed by a comma but it doesn’t have to be, especially if it’s short.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the clause following **but** is a direct reference to the preceding clause, you don't need a comma. If you are introducing a new or expanded idea after **but**, you do need a comma.

> I thought I would be able to complete the task but I could not.

However,

> I am able to play the piano very well, but I can't read music at all.